# How to delete multiple data with with the req.params.ids (multiple ids)

Tags: node.js

```
app.delete('/poems/delete:ids',(req,res,next)=>{
    //here req.params.ids carries the multiple id i.e 1,2,3

});
```

In the above code, 
how can I delete all data with the requested ids that is the data's containing ids 1,2,3

```
 this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/poems/delete' + ['1','3','4']);
```

Comment: 2 things - why use the `DELETE` verb with a CRUD URL? Also, if `ids` are arbitrary then you'd be best using `POST` and passing the IDs up in the body given URLs have a [maximum length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers).

Comment: ok, thank u so much.

Comment: can u please, why req.params.ids stores the values in the format like: 1,2,3 instead of [1,2,3] .

Answer (score 1):

The best practice in this case is to submit a `POST` request, whose body is an array of IDs.
In that case, your controller would get `req.body.ids` and delete them accordingly.

The `DELETE` HTTP Method is used for single deletions.